# Images in templates on civicrm spark

Tags: pdf, civicrm-spark

I am on civicrm spark running 5.32.beta1 and I cannot get images to work on templates with PDF document merge.

Since it's spark I have little control over the backend installation. As far as I can tell I can't use local image hosting located at "https://mysite.civicrm.org/sites/mysite.civicrm.org/files/civicrm/persist/contribute"  so I have tried hosting the images on our main organization webhost and using the url in an image tag. This appears to work fine for emails but will not generate in the pdf output.

I found this help relevant:
https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=22663.0.html
but since I'm on spark I don't believe I have any control over the civicrm version or the "allow_url_fopen" field. Can I only use any images already hosted on civicrm.org then? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I recommend posting a link to this question in the Spark channel at chat.civicrm.org!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add a custom field to contacts and upload a signature file to relevant users and then use that generated url. This work around isn't ideal as it means tying the image to a custom field that may not be relevant and a relative location hex link that looks roughly like this:

mysite.civicrm.org/civicrm/file?reset=1&id=2&eid=28&fcs=54ef7e8c1d8fc5b70133338bb1872353e

but we do what works. I would appreciate a better solution if anyone has one.